# How can I control my led strip on my windows via bluetooth?

Tags: python, strip, led

please help me, i wangt to connect my led strip but idk he said my device didnt not found

```
import time
import asyncio
import logging  # Don't forget to add this line
import trionesControl.trionesControl as tc

async def main():
    # Change the mac address to the one of your bulb or LED strip
    device = await tc.connect('FB:00:E0:82:AA:1F')
    
    await tc.powerOn(device)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: please add the complete text of the error, and what does success look like? did you modify the MAC as directed? are you using a supported setup?